# Error in user Registration of user using async controller

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have simple project using the template of Microsoft MVC's Authentication. upon debugging on the development machine and IIS express, I can create an new user I can Log in using its default controllers, But when i tried to publish it on IIS i catch a null reference exception on the Registration Process. here is the stacktrace:

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an    object.]
        TrabahoNow.Web.Controllers.<Register>d__8.MoveNext() +224
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +84
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37. <BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult  asyncResult) +10
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.   <InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.  <InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
        System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
        System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
        System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
        System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651796
        System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I have no Idea what cause it coz it is running on express. here is my controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName.ToUpper(),
                LastName = model.LastName.ToUpper(),
                MiddleName = model.MiddleName.ToUpper(),
                Email = model.Email,
                PhoneNumber = model.Phone,
                DesiredPosition = model.DesiredPosition,
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now,


            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                   await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                    

            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

This fails in IIS Server. Can someone help me figure this one out??

here is my set up..

**.NET 4.5.1**

**EF 6.0**

**MVC 5**

Comment: One of your model fields is null (likely the names) and the `ToUpper()` is throwing the exception. Run it in the debugger, and check your model.

Comment: the error come when i instantiate the class ApplicationUser at this line :

   var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName.ToUpper(),
                LastName = model.LastName.ToUpper(),
                MiddleName = model.MiddleName.ToUpper(),
                Email = model.Email,
                PhoneNumber = model.Phone,
                DesiredPosition = model.DesiredPosition,
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now,


            };
 it calls the dispose method of the controller

Comment: if i can only accept your comment as answer @BrendanGreen please post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the exception that you have, and confirmation that the error happens when you construct an instance of your `ApplicationUser` class, your issue is highly likely to be that either `model.FirstName`, `model.LastName` or `model.MiddleName` is null.

The call to `ToUpper()` will be the root cause of your exception.

Either check for null:

```
FirstName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName) ? null : model.FirstName
```

Or, if C# 6 is available to you, use the null propagation operator:

```
FirstName = model.FirstName?.ToUpper();
```

Comment: its on a nullable middleName you are absolutely right. thanks. c# approach is more elegant but no avail in my case for now. thanks again.